convert colored shapes in png into seperate objects in fabric js
I have a image png_image. when upload in canvas, I want to be able to select individual shapes and change its color in fabric js as shown in this
we can change individual colors
I tried converting the image into SVG and then doing some SVG parsing but that isnt creating seperate entities of the shapes, as id want to manipulate the color.
'
// Handle file upload and add to Fabric.js canvas
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleFileUpload(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        if (file.type === 'image/svg+xml') {
            // Handle SVG file
            try {
                fabric.loadSVGFromString(event.target.result, function(objects, options) {
                    if (!Array.isArray(objects)) {
                        console.error('SVG data is not an array:', objects);
                        return;
                    }

                    const svgGroup = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                    svgGroup.scaleToWidth(800);
                    svgGroup.scaleToHeight(800);
                    canvas.add(svgGroup).renderAll();
                    console.log('SVG added to canvas:', svgGroup);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error loading SVG:', error);
            }
        } else {
            // Handle image file
            const imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = event.target.result;
            imgObj.onload = function () {
                const image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                image.set({
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                });
                canvas.add(image);
            }
        }
    }
    
    reader.readAsText(file);
};

function changeSVGColor(newColor) {
    const activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (activeObject && (activeObject.type === 'path' || activeObject.type === 'rect' || activeObject.type === 'circle' || activeObject.type === 'polygon')) {
        activeObject.set('fill', newColor);
        canvas.renderAll();
        console.log('SVG color changed to:', newColor);
    } else if (activeObject && activeObject.type === 'group') {
        activeObject.getObjects().forEach((obj) => {
            if (obj.type === 'path' || obj.type === 'rect' || obj.type === 'circle' || obj.type === 'polygon') {
                obj.set('fill', newColor);
            }
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
        console.log('SVG color changed to:', newColor);
    } else {
        console.log('No SVG element selected or the selected object is not an SVG');
    }
}

'

You need to convert this from a bitmap image to a vector image, like .ai or .svg, and that conversion has to be done by a tool that can do the tracing that is needed to find the objects.  PhotoShop and Illustrator can do that, but a simple conversion doesn't.

I did create the shapes in inkscape using pen tool and exported it as SVG. Yet i am not able to change color. I get ERROR svg data is not an array.  The code is as follows is shown in the question

Where do you get that error?  When do you call changeSVGColor?  What gets returned in activeObject?  Is it the whole <svg> tag?  I suspect you're on the right path here, just some details.
